# Проблема с обработкой статических файлов в Django при использовании React

Tags: javascript, html, django, reactjs

Я столкнулся с проблемой обработки статических файлов в моем Django проекте при использовании React. У меня есть статические файлы в директории `D:\Chat_nextGen\MediaSave\frontend\build\static`, включая CSS, JS и медиафайлы.
Так же Джанго static, если нужно `D:\Chat_nextGen\MediaSave\static`
Я попытался подключить JS файл в моем шаблоне Django следующим образом:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/main.68afa4bf.js' %}"></script>
```

Однако, когда я запускаю проект, я получаю ошибки

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
indexChat.html:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend/build/static/js/main.68afa4bf.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Похоже, что Django не может найти этот файл.

Я проверил мои настройки статических файлов в settings.py и у меня есть подозрение, что я неправильно указал путь к static React

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'../MediaSave/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend', 'build', 'static'),
]
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь по этой проблеме.

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` — если вы не написали слэш в начале, то получилась относительная ссылка, которая вам всё сломала